# Meteor Legacy bundle served when using Headless Chrome (with puppeteer) on Debian 10

Tags: meteor, debian, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am using Meteor 1.10.2 on Debian 10 Buster. When loading the site in Headless Chrome (using `puppeteer`), the `web.legacy` bundle is used, which is causing lots of errors - my app doesn't support legacy browsers.

Example of error captured in the console:

no such file or directory, open `'<PATH_TO_APPLICATION>/bundle/programs/web.browser.legacy/dynamic/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/toConsumableArray.js'`

The user agent is set to
`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36` by default.

Is there any other feature detection that determines which bundle to use? What's causing the app to serve the legacy bundle in this situation?

**UPDATE**

Eventually I found the culprit (tldr: not a Meteor issue). Here's the explanation:
I was trying to create a pre-rendered version of the page to serve to crawlers / search engines but I failed to prevent client re-hydration and that's what was actually causing the errors. The solution was to first test if the app has already been pre-rendered server side before calling the client-side code (in my case just checking if the document body had a specific element as its child).

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately this has been [fixed with a PR](https://github.com/meteor/meteor-feature-requests/issues/333) in Meteor 1.10.1, that allows you to omit the legacy bundle explicitly on a build or test run.

You can simply use the `--exclude-archs` parameter like to:

```sh
$ meteor test --exclude-archs web.browser.legacy
```

Related: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v1101-2020-03-12

If you want to know more about the background on `web.browser.legacy` you can review these two resources:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v17-2018-05-28

https://blog.meteor.com/meteor-1-7-and-the-evergreen-dream-a8c1270b0901

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for the `build` command.

Comment: Good point, I think you will have to manually play around with the `modern-browsers` package to see how it will fit the headless chrome (referred in the last two links). If nothing on this helps you might open an issue on the Meteor repo.